# Accessing the value of a private variable in a method and making it global

Tags: variables, methods, flutter, global-variables

I have a method that gets a token from a login, in a class that also returns the token. I need to access the token's value in other classes. i.e. It needs to be global.

The code works and I do get the correct value. I just need that value to be accessible globally.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBarCall().getAppBar("Home"),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: () {
          _oauth2();
        },
      ),
      drawer: new SideDrawer(),
      body: HomePage(),

    );
  }
  _oauth2() {
    setState(() {
      authenticate(values);
    });
  }

  authenticate(...) async {
//    login code

    var token = tokenValue;

    return token; // <---- this value needs to be global
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var token;//now it is global, outside any class it the file

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {


    return Scaffold(
//...
      );
  }
   _oauth2() {
    setState(() {

     authenticate(values);

    });
  }

authenticate(...) async {
     login code

  token = tokenValue;//set the value here

return tokenValue;

}
}
```

Comment: just a dart thing :)